# ClassCastException: Unable to type cast object type into socket

Tags: java, sockets, casting

I'm trying to convert object type into socket type, so that I can use the properties of socket to get port number of particular node, which is present in my linked list. But I'm getting a class cast exception when I try the below code. I had also tried to convert Node type into Socket, which gave me an error, hence I'm trying to convert Object type into Socket type. Any assistance will be of great help.

```
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
            {
                Socket t;
                Object obj;
                obj = Node.List1.get(2);
                t=(Socket) obj;
                int p=t.get Port();
              }
```

Comment: Node.List1... seems like a backwards approach, or am I missing something? Does your list contain `Socket`s.

Comment: Show us how List1 is filled.

Comment: Is your object always of type Socket? Or is it a list of different types? Maybe you should use `obj as Socket` and then check if it is a null before proceeding.

Comment: What's the actual return type of `get(int)`?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just return `Socket` from it?

Comment: And why is it always 7 objects? Why not use foreach? Where are you using `i`? You're always getting the same object - `Node.List1.get(2)`

Comment: @Divi actually i want to get port no of each node but i was using trial and error method for 1 node at a time hence Node.List1.get(2) instead of Node.List1.get(i)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils My lists are made up of nodes, since i want to get each node's port no i'm converting Node to Object type and then to Socket, so i can use getPort() method which is available under Socket

Comment: How can you cast one object type to another? Woman to Human to Man?

Comment: @Makoto Node.List1.get(int) returns a Node from the list, i don't have Socket type in my list.

Comment: Then why on Earth would you try to cast it to a Socket? I feel you need to revisit a Node in a List. The node typically holds some sort of data, in your case hopefully a Socket. So returning the Node doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the list are not of type Socket. The exception tells you what type the object concerned was.